# Another spambot prevention method

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I know this question has been asked before but I didn't see the following solution anywhere else.

I have a website with a lot of forms and I'm looking for a way, without needing to edit the php for each form, to fend of the bots.

I'm proposing to use this but I wandered if anyone might have any thoughts or reasons why I should not?

```
    <form method="POST" action="enableJavascript.html">
        <!-- I change the action to a page to tell the user 
              that javascript is required-->

        <input name="action" value="contact.php" type="hidden"/>
        <!-- and add an input that contains the original action-->


        <input name="name"/>
        <input name="email"/>
        <input type="submit" value="submit"/>
    </form>
```

And here is the javascript / jQuery to handle posting the forms:

```
        $(function() {
            $('form').submit(function(e) {
                var $this = $(this);
                if (e.originalEvent) { // only change the action if the form was 
                                       // submitted via user input
                    e.preventDefault();
                    $this.attr('action', $('input[name=action]',$this).val());
                    $this.submit();
                }
            });
        });
```

I guess this would fail if bots are known to 'click' buttons, but I don't know if that's the case?

Comment: Might want to post this on code review http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Hmm... At first glance this is an interesting idea.

Comment: Your idea is just a minor obfuscation. It wouldn't fool a lot of heuristic crawlers, much less the more common replay bots.

Comment: I always find an absolutely positioned (out of sight) field as a `honey-pot` for bots is quite effective.. if the field is filled in, its a bot, if its not filled in then its human!

Answer (score 1):

This really won't work to stop bots and here's why. The bots will come in and scrape the field names from your form and then craft their own POST request. They're not going to see, let alone obey your JavaScript event stop.

What you should do is craft an AJAX page and have your form submit it that way. It makes it much harder for the bots to fill it out and submit because there's no `<form action="page.php">` to follow. The other way is to install a captcha, like [ReCaptcha](http://www.google.com/recaptcha/intro/)

Comment: If I understand correctly, the `action` in the HTML points to a page that just ignores the POST request. The JS code submits the form to the correct page. There's no JS trying to stop the submission.

Comment: Ah. So it is. It could fool some basic bots for sure, but it still not going to fool the smarter ones making the rounds today. I have a pretty complex cart and am constantly amazed at how adept they've become at filling fields and finding where the data is supposed to go. Remember, `contact.php` still takes a naked POST so all a bot has to do is figure that out and the obfuscation's cover is blown.